# How to resolve: "You cannot install the 32/64 bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine because you currently have 64/32 bit Office"?

Tags: microsoft-office, 64-bit, microsoft-access, 32-bit, microsoft-office-2016

Got a bit of chicken and egg here;
if I try to install Access Database driver 64-bit version, I see:

[image]

> You cannot install the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016 because you currently have 32-bit Office products
> installed. If you want to install 64-bit Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016, you will first need to remove the 32-bit installation
> of Office products. After uninstalling the following product(s),
> rerun setup in order to install
> 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016:
> Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component

No biggie, I thought – I'll use the 32-bit version:

[image]

> You cannot install the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016 because you currently have 64-bit Office products
> installed. If you want to install 32-bit Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016, you will first need to remove the 64-bit installation
> of Office products. After uninstalling the following product(s),
> rerun setup in order to install
> 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016:
> Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration

(Both windows had the title
“Microsoft Access database engine 2016 (English) Setup”.)

Hah..

I don't really get a choice about uninstalling particular components – the original install was an MSDN/Action Pack "double click this and it will install everything", so I'm not certain how to go about removing just this one thing it complains of.

Are there any workarounds I can try to get one of these to install?

Comment: @questionto42: I approved your suggested edit because you obviously put some effort into it.  But, in the future, please be more careful to get it right and not copy&paste blindly.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for accepting, though there is also a plausible reason for the misstyped x-bit versions: I took the text from my own error messages, not from the screenshots here, thinking they would be the same. And I had only 64-bit Office installed during testing. I remember that both messages only differed in the very first x-bit mentioned, with all the rest being equal. The sentence "You cannot install the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 because you currently have 64-bit Office products installed." really did appear. Strange coincidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any workarounds I can try to get one of these to install?

This is a relatively easy problem to solve.

1. Uninstall Office using the [automated tool](http://Uninstall%20Office%20automatically)
2. Reinstall [Office 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-2016-or-office-2013-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
3. Run the following command with an elevated command prompt:
   `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet`

Source: [How to install Microsoft.Ace.oledb 32 bit with Office 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710776/how-to-install-microsoft-ace-oledb-32-bit-with-office-64-bit/38079322#38079322)

Answer (score 9):

The OP likely prefers installing "ACEDB driver 64-bit" next to the other 64-bit Microsoft program.

In my case, I had "Microsoft 365" 64-bit (Microsoft Offic 365) installed, and I got the same chicken-and-egg problem. As the OP, I could not uninstall single components:

[image]

0. **No need to uninstall and reinstall anything.**
1. Press "Download" at [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

[image]

2. Choose `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe`

[image]

3. Run the executable from command prompt:

   ```
   C:\Users\myuser\Downloads>AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /quiet
   ```
4. Press OK for the administrator rights if asked for.

After this, my macro could fetch data from an Excel worksheet. I checked my local Microsoft Access of the Microsoft 365 package and it still worked.

Credits go to the accepted question and its source.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this worked for me even though I had uninstalled some office products before I saw this solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 32-bit version of Office, you need to remove the 64 bit version Click to Run. Do the simialr things if you have 64-bit version of Office.

To uninstall Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration, please try the steps below:

1. Press Win + R to open the Run window, type “installer” and click Enter to open the folder in File Explorer.
2. Add the column “Subject”. Right click the column headers, then click More and select Subject
3. Sort on the Subject column and scroll down until you locate the name “Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration”.
4. Right click the MSI file and choose uninstall.

Reference: [failed to install either 32bit or 64bit for Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76c99a6a-b809-4f50-8790-09c7c84f11af/failed-to-install-either-32bit-or-64bit-for-microsoft-access-database-engine-2016-redistributable?forum=officesetupdeployprevious);

[You receive the error message "You cannot install the 64-bit version of Office 2010 because you have 32-bit Office products installed"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office/cannot-install-64-bit-office-with-32-bit)

Comment: This worked perfect for me. Thank you.