# Microsoft Access Database Engine - cannot install either 32-bit nor 64-bit version

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, office365, microsoft-access, 32-bit

We have a workstation running Windows 10 (1709.16299.2166) with Office 365 on which I was asked to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 for a consultant.

After downloading the installer for the 64-bit version and trying to install it, I was greeted with the following error message:

> You cannot install the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 because you currently have 32-bit Office products
> installed. If you want to install 64-bit Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016, you will first need to remove the 32-bit installation of
> Office products. After uninstalling the following product(s), rerun
> setup in order to install 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016: Office 16 Click-to-run Extensibility Component

No problem I thought, I'll just download the 32-bit version and try again, but this time I was greeted with nearly the same message:

> You cannot install the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 because you currently have 64-bit Office products
> installed. If you want to install 32-bit Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016, you will first need to remove the 64-bit installation of
> Office products. After uninstalling the following product(s), rerun
> setup in order to install 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016: Office 16 Click-to-run Extensibility Component 64-bit
> Registration

Looking through the programs and features on this computer, I cannot seem to find the Office 16 Click-to-run Extensibility Component mentioned in both messages.

I've found a similar post ([You cannot install the 32/64 bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine because you currently have 64/32 bit Office](https://superuser.com/questions/1557350/you-cannot-install-the-32-64-bit-version-of-microsoft-access-database-engine-bec)) regarding Office 2016 with a suggestion to uninstall Office 2016. Unfortunately I cannot uninstall Office 365 on this workstation, as several processes depend on Office 365.

How can I install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 on this workstation, without having to uninstall Office?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution on MSDN (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/686e731a-cd6c-4c70-a1da-117ec0e90d56/quot-the-installation-of-this-package-failed-quot-in-microsoft-access-database-engine-2010?forum=accessdev). Apparently, the Office Click-to-run Extensibility Component is to blame. The solution is as described below:

To uninstall Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration, please try the steps below:

```
Press Win + R to open the Run window, type “installer” and click Enter to open the folder in File Explorer.

Add the column “Subject”. Right click the column headers, then click More and select Subject

Sort on the Subject column and scroll down until you locate the name “Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration”.

Right click the MSI file and choose uninstall.
```

Restart the installer for the Microsoft Access Database Engine, and you'll be fine. At least it was that way in my case - success!